# Determining a DVD drive's region code in OS X in C WITHOUT requiring that a DVD be in the drive

Tags: macos, dvd

Basically I run a network of computers and need to know what region code the drives of the various computers are set to.  I don't need to change the region, but I have no idea how to determine the region without going to each computer individually and sticking in a disc.  I tried using Apple's cocoa DVD playback framework, but that requires that a disk be inserted into the drive, which sort of defeats the purpose.

So are there any APIs that I can use to determine the region code on a Mac Pro's DVD drive without requiring that a disc be inserted?  I am willing to code in pretty much any language.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some utilities that are capable of dealing with DVD region settings on OS X: [DVD Info X, and Region X](http://xvi.rpc1.org/). DVD Info X will display the region code of your drive without requiring to have a DVD inserted.

Region X is more interesting because although it doesn't directly serve your purpose, [its source is available](http://xvi.rpc1.org/Region%20X%20source.zip). Looking at it I found that the `ScanAll` method in `Region X.m` is what you need. More specifically, the interesting case is the one where the disk name isn't found (because there's no disk mounted) and a SCSI command is used to find out the DVD drive's properties (the `printf` calls are my addition):

```
task = (*scsitaskinterface)->CreateSCSITask(scsitaskinterface);
if (task)
{
    cdb[0] = 0xa4;
    cdb[1] = 0x00;
    cdb[2] = 0x00;
    cdb[3] = 0x00;
    cdb[4] = 0x00;
    cdb[5] = 0x00;
    cdb[6] = 0x00;
    cdb[7] = 0x00;
    cdb[8] = (sizeof(DVDInfo) >> 8) & 0xff;
    cdb[9] = sizeof(DVDInfo) & 0xff;
    cdb[10] = 0x08;
    cdb[11] = 0x00;
    memset(&DVDInfo, 0, sizeof(DVDInfo));
    ProcessCDB(task, cdb, 12, DirIn, &DVDInfo, sizeof(DVDInfo), 30000);

    printf("drive region %#hhx\n", DVDInfo.driveRegion);
    printf("number of region changes left: %hhu\n", DVDInfo.numberUserResets);

    if (DVDInfo.rpcScheme == 0) RPC1++;
    if (DVDInfo.rpcScheme != 0) RPC2++;

    (*task)->Release(task);
}
```

I ran this on my Macbook Pro and the result was as expected.

Obviously you'll need to massage it in order to isolate that part into something you can use, but I think that this code will be a useful starting point.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Also you can translate the hex into something readable by using the DVDRegionCode enumeration(in the cocoa dvd playback framework)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer as such, but I have 2 links for you:

1. Code (for windows, not for Mac) that explains how to read the region:
   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/mydvdregion.aspx

Since these are pure SCSI commands - it is probably possible to adapt it for Mac.

1. ftp://ftp.san.ru/unix/soft.cvs/wine.git/wine-git/dlls/ntdll/cdrom.c
   There is Mac support there - and they read DVD region there too.